# How to get the correct URL for a JSON array

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I have some JSON objects in JSONbin.io that have the following structure:

```
{
  "employee_contributions": [
    {
      "transaction_id": "01",
      "staff_no": "12",
      "amount": "10000",
      "date": "20-2-2020"
   }
  ],
  "employer_contributions": [
    {
      "transaction_id": "01",
      "staff_no": "12",
      "amount": "10000",
      "date": "20-2-2020"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to access the object(s) in the employee_contributions array but I am getting a 404 error. I believe my URL is the problem but i do not know why. Here is the relevant main activity code:

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.jsonbin.io/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        yeeAPI yeeapi = retrofit.create(yeeAPI.class);
        Call<List<yee_contributions>> call = yeeapi.getYee_Contributions();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<yee_contributions>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<yee_contributions>> call, Response<List<yee_contributions>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    yee_contr.setText("code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }
                List<yee_contributions> contrs = response.body();
                for (yee_contributions yee_contributions : contrs){
                    String content = "";
                    content+=yee_contributions.getTransaction_id()+" ";
                    content+=yee_contributions.getStaff_no()+" ";
                    content+=yee_contributions.getAmount()+" ";
                    content+=yee_contributions.getDate()+"\n\n";
                    yee_contr.append(content);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<yee_contributions>> call, Throwable t) {
                yee_contr.setText(t.getMessage());

            }

        });
```

**And this is my interface:**

```
public interface yeeAPI {
    @GET("b/5e536928d3c2f35597f6ca46/3/employeee_contributions")
    Call<List<yee_contributions>> getYee_Contributions();
   
}
```

**My Model class:**

```
public class yee_contributions {
    private String transaction_id;
    private String staff_no;
    private String amount;
    private String date;

    public String getTransaction_id() {
        return transaction_id;
    }

    public String getStaff_no() {
        return staff_no;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

The base URL is fine. It is only when I add `/employee_contributions` to my endpoint, do I get the 404 error.

Comment: You can't access `employeee_contributions` in this way. Rather get whole data and then try to get `employeee_contributions` locally

Comment: this is your endpoint https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e536928d3c2f35597f6ca46/3/ and here you say you want a list of objects Call<List<yee_contributions>> if you want to access to employeee_contributions  you need to modify your logic

Comment: @Brokoth, Can you add your model class?

Comment: I have made the necessary edit @Md.Asaduzzaman

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman  Also, you say i "can't access `employeee_contributions` in this way". So, In which way can i access it? Or how do is sort it locally?

Comment: @FranciscoBarrios What i am asking is if there is a way to alter my url to retrieve the employee_contributions array of objects. If it is not possible, can you give more details in how i should "modify my logic" as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access `employeee_contributions` in this way. You have to get whole data first then parse `employeee_contributions` from it. To do so, You have to made some changes. Check below:

**Step - 1:** To align your `json` response you have to another model like below:

```
public class YeeResponse {
    private List<yee_contributions> employee_contributions;
    private List<yee_contributions> employer_contributions;

    //getter-setter

}
```

**Step - 2:** Change your API interface to incorporate this like below:

```
public interface yeeAPI {
    @GET("b/5e536928d3c2f35597f6ca46/3/")
    Call<YeeResponse> getYee_Contributions();
}
```

**Step - 3:** Change your implementation of `enqueue` and parse data like below:

```
Call<YeeResponse> call = yeeapi.getYee_Contributions();
call.enqueue(new Callback<YeeResponse>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<YeeResponse> call, Response<YeeResponse> response) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {

            return;
        }

        YeeResponse yeeResponse = response.body();
        List<yee_contributions> employee_contributions = yeeResponse.getEmployee_contributions();

        // Now loop through employee_contributions to get yee_contributions

        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<YeeResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        ....
    }

});
```

Comment: @Brokoth, Check my answer and let me know the update. Thanks

Comment: I am attempting to implement it yes

Comment: I would like to ask, is there a way to generate setters in yeeResponse and use them to POST data to JSONbin.io?